# p5.speech.js continuous won't become true

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've been playing around with p5.speech.js the past few days. I am able to record myself for short periods of time but it stops short. I later learned that there is a continuous bool that allows you to keep recording so I decided to implement it. I set it to true with the "let continuous = true". When I ran the code the p5.speechRec still said false within the console. When I tested the console.log at the bottom it the output was true as well so I'm a little confused as to if this is a bug, a problem with chrome, or just an error that I am missing. Thanks for your help.

```
    var myRec = new p5.SpeechRec(); // new P5.SpeechRec object
function setup()
{
    // graphics stuff:
    createCanvas(800, 400);
    background(255, 255, 255);
    fill(0, 0, 0, 255);
    // instructions:
    textSize(32);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text("say something", width/2, height/2);
    let continuous = true;
    let interimResults = false;
    myRec.start(continuous, interimResults);
    console.log(myRec);
    function speechRec(){
        if (speechRec.resultValue){
            createP(speechRec.resultString);
        }
    }
    console.log("cont bool: " + continuous);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like these are best answered by looking at the documentation for the library in question. Start by looking at [the P5.js libraries page](https://p5js.org/libraries/), which leads to the p5.speech documentation page [here](http://ability.nyu.edu/p5.js-speech/).

That documentation page says that `continuous` is a **property** of the `p5.SpeechRec` object, and it even links to some example code [here](https://github.com/IDMNYU/p5.js-speech/blob/master/examples/05continuousrecognition.html).

Basically, you can't just pass in a random value to the `start()` function and expect it to work. You have to set the `continuous` variable yourself:

```
var myRec = new p5.SpeechRec('en-US', parseResult); // new P5.SpeechRec object
myRec.continuous = true; // do continuous recognition
myRec.start(); // start engine
```

Also, I'm not sure what your `speechRec()` function inside your `setup()` function is meant to do since you never call it, but that's not directly related to your question.